# What kind of work elevates you to Dharmic Life?

Tags: karma, dharma

*"Anyone whose work is not meant to elevate him to Dharmic life, anyone whose religious ritualistic performances do not raise him to renunciation, and anyone situated in renunciation that does not lead him to devotional service to the Supreme Personality of Godhead, must be considered dead, although he is breathing."
—Srimad Bhagavatam 3.23.56*

So my question is ..what kind of work can elevates you to Dharmic life?
Since when I was young i worked as paramedic for 5 years, don't answer me the nurse or the doctor because it doesn't elevates you to nothing Dharmic. You will just face the sufferance of others or helping other physically .

Comment: See Gita Chapter 2 starting with verse 47. Also Chapter 4, verse 19-24 and 41, Chapter 5 verse 8-10 and 18. It is work without attachment that elevates, not a particular kind of work or a particular job.